# mozilla firefox неккоректное отображение шрифта

Tags: шрифты, firefox

Есть довольно популярный шрифт Roboto Bold. На первом скриншоте как он выглядит в хроме, на втором мозила. Вопрос, возможно ли сделать нормальным отображением в мозилле? Ибо он получается сильно жирным.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению, браузеры используют различные движки, которые отвечают за отображение графики, шрифтов и т.д., поэтому делать шрифты кроссбраузерными не получится, они все равно будут смотреться в каждом браузере различно.

Более подробно можете посмотреть в выпуске HTML шортов от html academy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFZWHLjNXdI